# joomla JA_MERO template problems

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-template

I am using [JA_MERO template for joomla 2.](http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-mero)5, but unfortunately

- it is rendering different layout on different browsers and screens, even on the same laptop with same browser, it renders different layouts.
- the main problem is, most of the times, it is not providing any layout, just a normal html links are shown.
- developers describe it as responsive but I observe that loading time of the website is too high.

If anyone know the solution kindly help me frends.

Comment: You haven't provided anything with which we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I am working on localhost. first problem is all the menu items are displayed as basic html links on left side.

Comment: Reinstall the template. Sounds like maybe some CSS files are missing. Does the default template work?

Comment: if any css file is missing, then how come 50% of the time it is rendered as per the design

Answer (score 0):

Check the template files. Can you find them physically? If not, then we already know the source of the problem. If you can find them you should check whether they are referenced correctly.

Comment: i can access the template files. all the files are referenced properly. half of the time website is rendered properly, but other half of the time basic html output

Comment: Can you distinguish the case when the website is rendered properly from the case when you have basic html output? Do you have any observation to make this distinction?

Comment: I could not notice anything which causing such problem